# Elastic Search JOIN

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to query elastic search for products a customer has ordered WITH the product details.

The product data looks like this:

```
|productid|productname|etc|
|P1|Product 1|...|
|P2|Product 2|...|
|P3|Product 3|...|
```

The order data looks like this:

```
|customerid|orderid|productid|
|C1|O1|P1|
|C1|O1|P2|
|C1|O2|P3|
|C2|O3|P1|
|C2|O3|P1|
```

I can query the order data by customer and get a bunch of productid values but then I have to query each product separately (or do a mass query with possibly hundreds of thousands of clauses).

Is there any way to query products by customerid? Or to query orders by customerid and get product details back?

Altenatively is there an efficient way to query hundreds of thousands of product details by id? i.e. a 2-stage approach: One query of productids by customer and then a second *single* query of products by productid.

Comment: There is no JOIN in elasticsearch, to get all the information you want without making multiple queries and using scripts to chain those queries you will need to change your data model. For example, instead of only the product id in the order data, you can save all the product information.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for approximations
1. The nested object / query option also mentioned in the comment above
2. has_ queries which sounds relevant in this particular case

Full details are available here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html

Comment: The problem is I can only have 1 join per index so if I join orders to products I cannot also join customers to products. I would have to duplicate all my products with all their attributes to a second index.

Comment: In this case you will either need to see normalize your data and store the same child documents in multiple places or choose another database more suitable for this :)